# How can I check if a non-input text element is clickable in Selenium? (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait, isenabled

I'm trying to check the clickability of a non-input text element (which can only be viewed but not edited). I have a test that where I want to assert that the view only text element (Ex: First Name) displayed on page can not be clicked.

I have tried using the `isEnabled()` method to check if the view only text element is enabled or not but the assertion is not happening correctly.

This is Bobcat Selenium code

Step definition code:

```
@Then("^I should verify that the First Name is not clickable$")
    public void iShouldVerifyThatTheFirstNameIsNotClickable() {
        assertEquals("Error: First Name is clickable", true, 
fullName.verifyClick());
}
```

Page Object code:

```
public boolean verifyClick() {
        if (firstName.isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }
}
```

Expected result: Since `firstName` is a view only element, the result of the `verifyClick()` method should be false so my `@Then("^I should verify that the First Name is not clickable$")` result should fail since the assertion is failing.

Actual result: `@Then("^I should verify that the First Name is not clickable$")` result is success.

Comment: The problem that you are running into is that the element *can* be clicked... it just won't do anything. Just as a user can click an element that is disabled, but it does nothing. Instead I would focus on the classes of the element when it is disabled. I'm assuming that certain classes exist on the element when it is disabled that give it that disabled look. Check to see if those classes exist on the element and use that to determine disabled or not.

Comment: BTW... your `verifyClick()` method can be reduced to `return firstName.isEnabled()`.

Comment: The real question here, is what is your definition of clickable?  Are you checking it's not an anchor, or a button, or a specific HTML tag.  Or are you really trying to check that doesn't have a JavaScript listener bound to it?  Maybe you want to check it's not wrapped, or referenced, by a label tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a part of the selenium Java bindings that could be useful to you here.  In [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) you'll find a function called `elementToBeClickable()`. This returns a boolean that's false whenever the element is not clickable for any reason, and true when it can receive a click.  So you just want to wait and see if that function returns true.  Selenium handles that as well with the [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class.

So you'll need to import both of those, and then you can do something like this:

```
//setting the timeout for our wait to be 20 seconds (you can use whatever you want)
WebDriverWait myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver,20); 
try {
    WebElement myElement = myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(firstName)));
    //assert test failed!
}
catch(timeoutException timeout) {
    //whatever you want to do when the element is not clickable
}
```

Comment: While this will work, you will wait for 20s to find out that it's not clickable.

Comment: Yes, maybe something like 5s would be more reasonable.  The user can pass in whatever parameter they like.

Comment: Problem is `elementToBeClickable` checks if element `isDisplayed` and `isEnabled`, and will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Sers could you provide a little more detail?  Why does that not achieve the user's goal?

Comment: @C.Peck for any html element not support `disabled` attribute ([support elements](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp)), `isEnabled` return true.